# how to concatenate two string variables in the javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, model-view-controller

i want to show two variables data combinly in the title of a marker in google map.
in marker title i want to show the id as well as time of the record. but while im concatenating both the things showing error in this line  **title:@Model.AssetTrackers[0].deviceid +  markerSettings.time.**. error is 13ef is undefined. 13ef is deviceid.

code

```
 function addMarker(markerSettings) {
        if (!insidePolygon(markerSettings)) {
            //alert(markerSettings.deviceId + " is out of fence");
            deviceIds.push(markerSettings.deviceId);
            times.push(markerSettings.trackTime);
            var deviceId = $.grep(deviceIds, function( a ) {
                return a === markerSettings.deviceId;
            })

            var trackTime = $.grep(times, function (b) {
                return b === markerSettings.time;
            })
            if(deviceId.length == 1){
                $.notify(markerSettings.deviceId + " is out of fence", {
                    className: 'error',
                    clickToHide: true,
                    autoHide: false,
                    globalPosition: 'top right'
                });
            }
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: markerSettings,
                map: map,
            title:@Model.AssetTrackers[0].deviceid +  markerSettings.time,//error getting
                label:labels[labelIndex++ % labels.length],
                icon : "https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png"
            });
        }
```

Comment: Please state what the error actually is.

Comment: Use the concatenation operator `+`?

Comment: I suspect that `@Model.AssetTrackers[0].deviceid` is a template variable, which is being dumped into JavaScript without care for generating a syntactically-correct string value. `title: asdf123 + markerSettings.time` would not be valid due to an undefined variable, and that's a best-case here...

Comment: You still need to wrap `@Model.AssetTrackers[0].deviceid` in quotes.

Comment: how to wrap it with quotes can u please tell me. im not getting